# unsolved reference: KorgeGradlePlugin at apply<KorgeGradlePlugin>()

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, korge

Has anyone experienced unresolved reference in `build.gradle.kts`?

The relevant part of my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import com.soywiz.korge.gradle.*

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")}
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.soywiz:korge-gradle-plugin:2.7.0")
    }

    apply<KorgeGradlePlugin>()

    korge {
        id = "mycode"
        targetJvm()
    }
}
```

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2022.2 on MacBook Pro M1. Korge version is 3.0.0 and Kotlin version 222-1.7.10-release-334-IJ3739.54.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Korge documentation](https://docs.korge.org/korge/gettingstarted/setup/gradle-plugin/) seems to be a little bit outdated.

You can [use a Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html) by adding it to the `plugins` block, like so:

```
plugins {
    id("com.soywiz.korge") version "3.0.0"
}
```

The version can be found on [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.soywiz.korge/com.soywiz.korge.gradle.plugin), and I found the id by looking at the [`build.gradle.kts`](https://github.com/korlibs/korge-plugins/blob/324e3295f4176b6fe63ce6c0dcccbfe8f1bb8582/korge-gradle-plugin/build.gradle.kts#L18) in their plugin source code.

There's a difference between a Gradle plugin and loading a dependency via gradle.
The plugins should be loaded via the id and version in the plugins block, and usually don't require anything in the dependencies block.
A plugin then only provides a DSL to use in your `build.gradle`.
When you specify something in the dependencies block, that's a dependency of your source code.